# Google Directions on mobile applications, walking distance between two points - minimize response

Tags: javascript, directions

I'm working on a mobile app and I would like to calculate the distance between two points using the Google Directions API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions).

I have a list of places and I would like to show this list ordered by distance (from the user position). This can be done performing a request using Google API, look at the following post, there is a working example: 
[Android: how to get the walking distance between two geo coordinats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963864/android-how-to-get-the-walking-distance-between-two-geo-coordinats)).

My questions:

1) Is it possible to calculate the distance from one origin (my current position) to several points (places) using just one request?

2) Is it possible to reduce the size of the response (in order to reduce network traffic)? I just need distance + required time. I would like tho show the map only when the user click the item in the list.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Mauro

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [google.maps.DirectionsLeg](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsLeg) and [this example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints.html).

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Actually, my problem is a little bit different. I have one origin point (A) and 3 arrival points (B, C, D). I'd like to calculate all the three distances and the find the shortest one. Is it possible to do it using just one request?
Another issue that I am currently encountering is the size of the Google Response. I did a test using one origin and one arrival point and I got a 30k size json-response. Since I'm planning to minimize the network traffic, 30k with useless additional information seemed to be too much for just one API call.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mauro The second link is what you want. Check out the [doc](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Waypoints) on it. "By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass optimizeWaypoints: true within the DirectionsRequest to allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by **rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order**." As for the size of the response I don't think they have options for that. You can look into their documentation though.